# Doctrine2 PostgreSQL schema restriction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I have a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension installed. It has 3 other schemas (tiger, tiger_data, topology) and the public. My tables should be in the public schema, but right now i can't run doctrine:schema:update, because of this error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology
LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "topology"."topology_id_...
```

So i can't generate my tables from my entities (or just dump the DDL sql).

Can i restrict the doctrine somehow to analyse only public scheme and skip the others?

Comment: Have you installed `PostGIS` as `Postgres` user?

Comment: Yes. Was i supposed to do it with the regular user? i mean the create extension commands.

Comment: Remove this extension and install as your Symfony2 user

Comment: I've just tried, but it seems that the owner privilege is not enough. User needs to be superuser.

ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the extension by superuser you can grant privileges on the required schemas to your default user.

```sql
-- tables and views
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA topology TO some_username;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
IN SCHEMA topology
GRANT SELECT
ON TABLES
TO some_username;

-- sequences
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA topology TO some_username;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
IN SCHEMA topology
GRANT SELECT, USAGE
ON SEQUENCES
TO some_username;

-- usage
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA topology TO PUBLIC;
```

Here's my template for Ansible to prepare the database to be used with PostGIS: https://gist.github.com/leafnode/5b416efe87ed152b12bb24b1dc4f5f14 Some privileges could be tightened if you use the database in a shared environment.